# how to modify rnn cells in pytorch?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, nlp

If I want to change the compute rules in a RNN cell (e.g. GRU cell), what should I do?
I do not want to implement it via for or while loop considering the issue of efficiency.
I have viewed the source code of pytorch, but it seems that the major components of rnn cells are implement in c code which I cannot find and modify.
You can answer this question through an example: implement GRU cell without the existing version.

thank you ~

Comment: *"You can answer this question through an example: implement GRU cell without the existing version."* `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Any other wish?

Comment: ... and without "for" or "while" loop?  This vanilla way will lead at least 10 times slower than standard GRU.   And the "GRU cell"  I used may be ambiguous. Actually, I want to modify cells to implement GRU layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you implement it "via for or while loop".
Since Pytorch 1.0 there is JIT https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html that works pretty well (probably better to use the latest git version of PyTorch because of recent improvements to JIT), and depending on your network and implementation in can as fast as a native PyTorch C++ implementation (but still slower than CuDNN).

You can see example implementations at https://github.com/pytorch/benchmark/blob/master/rnns/fastrnns/custom_lstms.py

Comment: Thank you. I tested it with batchsize=64, timesteps=512, input_dim=1024, output_dim=128. rnntype=gru. run 10 times on 1080-ti and only consider forward procedure. naive for loop takes 516ms, a jit class with for loop takes 506ms, gru api takes 204ms. And the for loop is much sensitive to the timesteps length. If we have 2048 timesteps, for loop slow 4 time and gru api version only slow 3 times.

Comment: You didn't disable the CuDNN, right? The nn.GRU Pytorch class calls CuDNN, that's why it's so fast. Try with `torch.backends.cudnn.enabled = False`, the nn.GRU should be much slower, close to python loop with JIT.

Comment: No, I didn't ... and that's the sad story ~ CuDNN is really strong ~ thank you~